# How to access "layout"-field inside gridelements

Tags: typo3, tx-gridelements

In a installation of Typo3 7.6, I have a simple gridelement, just providing two columns.

When adding a gridelement in the backend, I can set appearence -> layout to one of several values.

The configuration of gridelements via typoscript adds its values to **tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup**

Is there a possibility to add a class to the typoscript-setup, depending on the value in "layout"?

Answer (score 0):

Since the value belongs to the grid container itself, there is no special magic necessary to get it from the record. A simple dataWrap should do the job.

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {    
  1 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
  1 {
    dataWrap = <div class="layout-number-{field:layout}">|</div>
    columns {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```